# remove spaces and closure tag of a xml line

Tags: haskell

I have an issue with formatting an IO String, and don't know how i could do that.

For example:

```
tryA (arrIO (\s -> hPutDocument (\h -> hPutStrLn h 
=<< readProcess "grep" ["-n",s,"camera2.owl"] "")))
```

As it was mentioned on my post asked `today` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230577/hputstrln-with-io-string), i figured out that my String `s` has a lot of things which i don't need it.

For example, normally i have that String on `s`:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#SLR">   </owl:Class>
```

And what i want , it is to delete the spaces available after `>` and remove the close tag which is `</owl:Class>`

How could i do that on haskell ?
I must do the transformation before it is sent to my grep function.

P.S. : 
Maybe i could use some regular expressions with a type `<.>` and after that he removes it. (Doing the lesser match of course,or it will give me the full match)

Comment: Could you please reformat your code snippet? The extensive nesting is rather hard to grasp within a single line. Also, I wanted to take a stab at it myself, but then I noticed the parentheses don't match.

Comment: Sorry about the parentheses, didn't saw earlier. Thanks for the help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there are always spaces before the closing tag and the tag itself doesn't have them, the most minimal way to remove it from a String to me would be:

```
import Data.List

removeClosingTag = unwords . init . words
```

From a GHCi session I just ran:

```
λ> let myString = "<owl:Class rdf:about=\"http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#SLR\">   </owl:Class>"
λ> (unwords . init . words) myString
"<owl:Class rdf:about=\"http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#SLR\">"
```

**EDIT**: Warning: init is not total and will give you a runtime error on an empty list [].