# readInputLine with IO String

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, haskeline

I would like to read an input string with a custom prompt, however the prompt string comes from impure context, thus I can't use `readInputLine` as is. I've tried to implement a function based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230577/hputstrln-with-io-string)

```
getLineIO :: MonadException m => IO String -> InputT m (Maybe String)
getLineIO ios = do
    s <- ios
    res <- getInputLine s
    lift res
```

but I get an error

```
   Couldn't match expected type ‘InputT m String’
                with actual type ‘IO String’
    Relevant bindings include
      getLineIO :: IO String -> InputT m (Maybe String)
        (bound at Main.hs:38:1)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: s <- ios
    In the expression:
      do { s <- ios;
           return $ getInputLine s }
```

**Update:** got it to work based on @bheklilr's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37926258/165753)

```
getLineIO :: (MonadException m, MonadIO m) => IO String -> InputT m (Maybe String)
getLineIO ios = do
      s <- liftIO ios
      getInputLine s
```

Comment: You probably just need to use `lift` to convert your `IO String` into an `InputT IO String` i.e. `s <- lift ios`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
do
    s <- ios
    res <- getInputLine s
    lift res
```

Gets de-sugared into

```
ios >>= \s -> (getInputLine s >>= \res -> lift res)
```

Where

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

This type signature means that `m` has to be the same `Monad` instance throughout.  You've given it `ios :: IO String` and `\s -> getInputLine s :: String -> InputT n (Maybe String)`, but `m` can't be both `IO` and `InputT n`, hence the compiler error.

You can just use `liftIO` on `ios` provided `instance MonadIO m => MonadIO (InputT m)` is defined, which it is.  So you can just do

```
getLineIO :: (MonadException m) => IO String -> InputT m (Maybe String)
getLineIO ios = do
    s <- liftIO ios
    res <- getInputLine s
    lift res
```

Comment: Thanks, are you using `m` for both `MonadException` and `MonadIO`?

Comment: @dimid `liftIO` requires that the `Monad` you're in also implements `MonadIO`.  After looking at the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline-0.7.2.3/docs/System-Console-Haskeline-MonadException.html) it appears that `MonadException` already requires `MonadIO`, so you can drop that requirement.  However, if you were working in a different `Monad` it is possible to have multiple constraints on your particular `m`.  It's not uncommon to see `mtl` based code with constraints like `(MonadState s m, MonadWriter w m, MonadIO m) => ...`